# Xamarin SLComposeServiceViewController crash when updating UI component

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am creating a Xamarin iOS share extension.
Everything works fine, but when i try to change something on UI, the app crash. I have no error message. In fact, i want to display something in textview if something fails when the user push post button. I have also tried to put an alertview or to create my own custom post button.

Here is the code:

```
        NSExtensionItem imageItem = ExtensionContext.InputItems[0];
        if (imageItem == null)
            return;

        NSItemProvider imageItemProvider = imageItem.Attachments[0];
        if (imageItemProvider == null)
            return;

        if (!imageItemProvider.HasItemConformingTo(UTType.Image))
            return;

        TextView.Text = "ok this works here";

        imageItemProvider.LoadItem(UTType.Image, null, (NSObject image, NSError error) =>
        {
            var st = new MemoryStream();

            if (image == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var url = image as NSUrl;
            if (url == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var img = UIImage.LoadFromData(NSData.FromUrl(url));
            img.AsPNG().AsStream().CopyTo(st);
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    this.TextView.Text = "CODE CRASH HERE";
                    this.TextView.TextColor = UIColor.Red;
                });
            }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        });
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if the control is null when it hits the line of code where you assign text to your textview?

Comment: The control is not null. Why should it be null ?

Comment: If it isn't intialised at the point at which it tries to update the text property, then it can be null. the weird thing is that aside from ensuring it's ran on the main UIThread there isn't anything strange or unusual about your code.

Comment: Okay so what should i do ? What i want to do is to call a webservice for uploading my image and display an error message somewhere if there is a problem. I have also tried UIAlertControler but it crashes too